# Python functions and for loops

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programming and I do not seem to get the right behavior from a FOR loop.

I've got a **list of ids**, and I want to iterate a **".gtf" file** (*tab separated multi-line*) and extract from it some values corresponding to those ids.

It seems that the construction of the regex is not working correctly inside the findgtf function. From the second iteration onward, the "**id**" variable passed to the function is not used for the regex pattern of "**sc**" variable and subsequently, the pattern matching doesn't work. Do I need to reinitialize the variables "**id**" or/and "**sc**" before each iteration?

I so, could you tell me how to achieve that

Here's is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
import sys, os, re
#Usage:gtf_parser_4.py [path_to_dir] [IDlist]

#######FUNCTIONS######################################

def findgtf(id, gtf):

    id=id.strip()#remove \n
    #print "Received Id: *"+id+"* post-stripped"

    for line in gtf:
        seq, source, feat, start, end, score, strand, frame, attribute = line.strip().split("\t")
        sc = re.search(str(id), str(attribute))

        if sc:

            print "Coord of "+id+" -> Start: "+str(start)+" End: "+str(end)

###########################MAIN#########################
#Arguments retrieval
mydir = sys.argv[1]
#print"Directory : "+mydir
IDlist = sys.argv[2]
#print"IDlist : "+IDlist
path2ID = os.path.join(mydir, IDlist)
#print"Full IdList: "+path2ID
#lines to list
IDlines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(path2ID)]

#Open and read dir
for file in os.listdir(mydir):
    if file.endswith(".gtf"):

        path2file = os.path.join(mydir, file)
        #print"Full gtf : "+path2file
        gtf = open(path2file,"r")

        for id in IDlines:
            print"ID submitted to findgtf: "+id
            fg = findgtf(id, gtf)
        gtf.close()
```

And here are the results retrieved from the console (submitted an Idlist with 3 ids: **LX00_00030, gyrB, LX00_00065** ):

```
    ID submitted to findgtf: LX00_00030
    Coord of LX00_00030 -> Start: 4299 End: 5303
    ID submitted to findgtf: gyrB
    ID submitted to findgtf: LX00_00065
```

As you can see the first ID worked correctly but the second an third do not yield any result (although they do if their order is switched in the IDlist).

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you at least pinpoint in which for loop the "error" occurs?

Comment: I wish I knew, but I believe it is in the FOR loop from the function "findgtf", because I get the result from it, but only for the first Id the function receives.
I thought I may be some obvious and naive mistake due to my inexperience...
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: One place to start is to make sure your for loops are looping as many times as you expect by adding some print statements. If there are 10 IDs then you should see that print 10 times and if there are 20 lines in your gtf file then you should have 200 printed lines if you put a print statement at the beginning of your findgtf loop. If that checks out then your problem most likely comes from your regex search

Comment: Please narrow this down to a [mcve].

Comment: @SirParselot , you are completely right, it seems that the construction of the regex is not working correctly. It appears that from the second iteration onward, the "id" variable passed to the function is not used for the regex pattern of "sc" variable and subsequently, the pattern matching doesn't work.
Do I need to reinitialize the variables "id" or/and "sc" before each iteration? I thought that was done automatically every time the function was called...
Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean the `id` variable isn't used for the regex pattern? Should it be a different variable or different regex pattern to find sc after the first iteration? Is it one `id` matches one line or can it match multiple?

Comment: I thought that the id variable didn't reach the regex, but as @Blckknght explained, that wasn't the problem, the problem was related to:
"To make your code work, you need to seek back to the start of the file before iterating over it again"
The effect of this issue seemed the same, no results were retrieved, as if the regex pattern was not in use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are trying to repeatedly iterate over the same file object. A file keeps track of the position you've read to internally, so when you've read to the end, you can't read any more!

To make your code work, you need to `seek` back to the start of the file before iterating over it again.

```
for id in IDlines:
    print"ID submitted to findgtf: "+id
    gtf.seek(0) # seek to the start of the file
    fg = findgtf(id, gtf)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Blckknght, I would have never figured that out without your help...this issue was far beyond my current knowledge of Python...
So, every time a file is scanned, it has to be reset to "file.seek(0)" to be set at the beginning, right?  Is there any way to open files so that they do not need to be reset as in my case?
Thanks again

Comment: They only need to be reset between repeated iterations. I did it at the top of the loop because that seemed easiest, but it also works at the end of the loop. You're getting one more `seek` than necessary in either case. An alternative solution would be to read all the lines from the file just once in to a list, then iterate over the list (which you can do as many times as you want).

Comment: Thank you @Blckknght, that was exactly the solution I was looking for.